# JavaScript Regex to check that the searched string is preceded by either nothing, or spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

```
var requestData = {};

var byPattern = /by=(\w+)/;
var value = byPattern.exec(stringToSearch);
if (value && value.length === 2)
    requestData.by = value[1];
```

The first problem with this regex, was that if `stringToSearch` is for example "standby=foo", it matched and returned "foo". I want it to fail there. I want the regex to match only if there is *nothing* before "by", or *spaces*.

So I replaced by `/^\s*by=(\w+)/`

That's better, but I want the regex to match if `stringToSearch` is for example "city=paris by=foo". It should match and return "foo". Not the case here :/

Can someone help me fix the regex? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *spaces or nothing* before the capturing group, that would be `( +|^)`:

```
/( |^)by=(\w+)/
```

Technically, I'm matching *space or nothing*, but the effect is the same.

Comment: @Blackbird The one that you use. If you want to reject `stand-by=3`, choose mine ;-)

Comment: If you want to match white-space in general (not just a space bar, but tab, newline, &c.), use `/(\s|^)by=(\w+)/`

Answer (score 5):

the magic word is `\b`:

```
var byPattern = /\bby=(\w+)/;
console.log(byPattern.exec("by=3"));
console.log(byPattern.exec(" by=3"));
console.log(byPattern.exec("standby=3"));
```

Only the first two are matched, which is (I think) what you want.

Comment: `\bby` also matches `by` in `stand-by=3`

Comment: That looks nice. I don't know about the backspace in regex. How does this magic work? It also works for `city=paris by=3`

Comment: @Blackbird `\b` is word boundary, not backspace.

Comment: @Malvolio thanks, but as Jan wrote, his solution has the advantage of not matching when preceded by "-"